# combining two etables with rbind not working

Tags: r

I am trying to combining two tables below but not working as expected , not showing any error but tables are not joining.

```
library(expss)
library(dplyr)

df <- mtcars
df$vs <- 1
N_row <- 3
banner1 <- list(df$vs)

t1 <- cro_cpct(df$qsec,banner1)
t1 = capture.output(t1)
t1 = c(t1[1:(N_row + 3)], "", stringr::str_pad("...", 
                                              nchar(t1[1]), "both"), "", t1[(length(t1) - 
                                                                                       N_row):length(t1)])
t1 %>% paste(collapse = "\n") %>% cat()


Min <- function(x) min_col(x, na.rm = TRUE)
Max <- function(x) max_col(x, na.rm = TRUE)
t2 <- cross_fun(df, df$qsec, col_vars = banner1, 
                      fun = combine_functions(Max = Max, Min = Min, `Valid N` = valid_n))

t_all <- list(t1, t2)
t_all <- rbind(t_all[[1]], "", t_all[[2]])
```

Comment: Where ist `cro_cpct()` from? What is your desired output? Replace `%>%` with `|>` or specify `library(dplyr)`.

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Still a lot missing. Try to run your code in a fresh R session.

Comment: yes i have updated it all

Comment: On my machine a warning is issued after running the last function `rbind()`: *Warning message:
In rbind(deparse.level, ...) :
  number of columns of result, 2, is not a multiple of vector length 13 of arg 1*. I get a result by running `t_all`. As long as you do not demonstrate your desired result, I cannot comment on that.

Comment: i have updated the expected output in the question

Comment: use `add_rows` instead of `rbind`

Comment: @GregoryDemin add_rows is still not working , tab <- add_rows(t1,t2) tried this way but t1 table is becoming blank

Comment: It's because your `t1` is character vector rather than table.

Comment: @GregoryDemin then what is the solution ..?? i want the above like output

Answer (score 0):

The two objects do not fit together, t1 is a character vector, t2 is a dataframe (etable).

rbind() does not know how to put these two objects together.

You can use etable's custom print method to convert t2 first into a dataframe and then into a character-vector. After that, you can simply concatenate t1 and t2.

```
t2.2 <- apply(print(t2), 1, \(x) paste(x, collapse = ','))
t_all = c(t1, "", t2.2)
```

and print it to console:

```
cat(t_all, sep='\n')
```

However, it all seems a bit cumbersome. There are countless packages that calculate statistics of vectors. DescTools for example is a great package for such tasks, try this:

```
library(DescTools)
Desc(df$qsec)
```

Comment: but i want to export the output in excel only

Comment: then why didn't you mention in your question?
however exporting to Word as easy with DsescTools:
wrd <- GetNewWrd()
ToWrd(Desc(df$qsec))
From there you can copy/paste the needed information to Excel.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
library(expss)
library(dplyr)

df <- mtcars
df$vs <- 1
N_row <- 3
banner1 <- list(df$vs)



Min <- function(x) min_col(x, na.rm = TRUE)
Max <- function(x) max_col(x, na.rm = TRUE)
t2 <- cross_fun(df, df$qsec, col_vars = banner1, 
                fun = combine_functions(Max = Max, Min = Min, `Valid N` = valid_n))

t1 <- cro_cpct(df$qsec,banner1)

t1_head = head(t1, 3)
t1_middle = head(t1, 1)
t1_middle[,-1] = "..."
t1_middle[["row_labels"]] = gsub("^(.+?)\\|.+", "\\1|...", t1_middle[["row_labels"]])
t1_tail = tail(t1, 4)

t_all = add_rows(t2, " ", t1_head, t1_middle, t1_tail)
```